# Вопросы от чайника

Tags: angular, angular2, angular4, angular5, angular-routing

Только начал изучать Angular, и сразу возникло несколько вопросов. Буду благодарен если вы поможете разобраться с ними. Спасибо.

Вопросы:

1. В мануале указано, что для запуска Angular нужно ввести команду `ng serve --open`. После запуска автоматически запускается браузер с URL localhost:4200. Но при попытке перейти по дефолтному адресу (используя 80 порт) localhost/myapp браузер просто отображает листинг файлов в директории. Вопрос - как запустить Angular на 80/443 порту?
2. Можно ли публиковать сайты, созданные с использованием Angular на хостинге? Насколько мне известно, на хостинге доступен только FTP доступ, а выполнение команд недоступно. Следовательно запустить команду `ng serve --open` не выйдет. Получается что нужно заказывать не хостинг, а полноценный VDS сервер для запуска сайта с Angular?
3. Я всегда писал на HTML/CSS/JS. Какие преимущества даст работа с Angular (помимо "реактивных" приложений)?
4. Можете привести примеры сайтов, написанных на Angular?

Прошу не кидаться камнями, так как в веб разработке я относительно недавно. Спасибо еще раз.

Answer (score 2):

1. Дефолтный порт для angular приложений - 4200. Если вы запускаете приложение стандартным образом то, конечно, на других портах вы ничего не удивите.
2. Можно. Надо собрать приложение командой `ng build --prod`. На выходе по пути `PROJECT_ROOT/dist` вы найдёте ряд html, css, js файлов. Поместите их в папку веб-сервера на хостинге и ваше приложение (если везде и всюду всё стандартно настроено) будет доступно на 80 и 443 портах (для http и  https протоколов).
3. Очень много. Долго перечислять. Лично мне нравится, что TypeScript какую-то типо-безопасность предоставляет и архитектуру, похожую на то, что я вижу в Android разработке.
4. https://dont-play-with-google.com/ - в подвале сайта есть ссылки на исходники.

---

P.S. Желательно следовать правилу - один вопрос в одном вопросе. Список вопросов в одном вопросе - не очень практика. И заголовок следует делать таким, чтобы из него была ясна суть вопроса. Даже если при этом в самом теле вопроса останется лишь заголовок повторить. Если так делать - восприятие вопроса отвечающими радикально повысится, ибо сразу будет ясно о чём вопрос. И поисковики лучше это всё проиндексируют.